# Ajax update executes once though event occurs many times

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, events, primefaces

I'm starting to learn Primefaces framework, based on JSF and AJAX and I'm having some trouble.

I was trying a simple example such as having an **inputText** and I was trying to set a counter that increments its value every time a key is pressed on the *inputText*. To do this I used AJAX and a Bean. The problem is that the counter only is increased the first time, after that it remains the same. Here's my code:

**WEB PAGE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>AJAX LISTENER</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText id="counter">
            <p:ajax update="out" event="keypress" listener="#{counterBean.increment}"/>
        </h:inputText>
        <br/>
        AJAX listener = <h:outputText id="out" value="#{counterBean.count}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**BEAN**

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class counterBean {
    private int count;
    public counterBean() {
        this.count = 0;
    }
    public void increment(){
        this.count = this.count +5;
    }
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging through the event? Is it called every time you press a button? If so, is `this.count` the second time **0** again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counterbean needs to be viewscoped.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to : http://www.primefaces.org/documentation

In your case the better event is keyup
I don't think it has a keypress event in primefaces.

Section 8.3 in the user guide 4.0

- Ok your answer is actually very simple, I did testing and after finally realising the stupidity of it all...

Your ManagedBean is only RequestScoped - thus it's getting re-initalised every request...
Change it to @ViewScoped.

A great doco on beans is : 
http://balusc.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes

Comment: I've also tried with that event. I have been reading the PF users guide but can't find a solution there! PD: there is a keypress event :)

Comment: Oh nice has it - see my updated answer, change your scope of your bean :)